# Reading values from database and updating an existing xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

Using SQL Server 2008 and table has some values like this:

```
EMPN ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE
---- ---------- --------- -----------
7341 SMITH      CLERK     17-DEC-1980
7482 ALLEN      SALESMAN  20-FEB-1981
```

My XML is in sharefolder

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <empno>7369</empno>
        <ename>SMITH</ename>
        <job>CLERK</job>
        <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate>
    </employee>    
    <employee>
        <empno>7499</empno>
        <ename>ALLEN</ename>
        <job>SALESMAN</job>
        <hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Now need to change my existing XML based on the database values (EMPN)

How do we do that?

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Take a look here if you don't know how to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml

Comment: Do you need to modify existing XML by replacing values in relevant <employee> nodes, or can you generate new XML for employees?

Comment: Need to modify the existing XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint at first:

- Avoid culture specific or (even worse!) language specific date/time formats like `17-DEC-1980`. Especially *within XML* you should use ISO8601.

The table data you show and the XML you provide do not cover the same IDs, hence I assume, that you need to add the new employees as new sub-nodes:

```
DECLARE @existingXML XML=
'<employees>
  <employee>
    <empno>7369</empno>
    <ename>SMITH</ename>
    <job>CLERK</job>
    <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>7499</empno>
    <ename>ALLEN</ename>
    <job>SALESMAN</job>
    <hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate>
  </employee>
</employees>';

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE(MPN INT,ENAME VARCHAR(100),JOB VARCHAR(100),HIREDATE DATE);
INSERT INTO @tmpTable VALUES
 (7341,'SMITH','CLERK','17-DEC-1980')
,(7482,'ALLEN','SALESMAN','20-FEB-1981');

DECLARE @NewXml XML=
(
SELECT
    (
    SELECT e.MPN AS [empno]
          ,e.ENAME AS [ename]
          ,e.JOB AS [job]
          ,e.HIREDATE AS [hiredate]
    FROM @tmpTable AS e
    FOR XML PATH('employee'),TYPE
    ) AS NewXML
);
SET @existingXML.modify(N'insert sql:variable("@NewXML") as last into (/employees)[1]');

SELECT @existingXML;
```

If you need to *synchronize* a table's and and the XML's data, I'd shredd the whole thing to a derived table, use some `MERGE` approach on row-wise data and rebuild the XML from scratch.

Comment: I want to update the existing values. Not to insert new values. Thanks

Comment: @Somashekhar In your table's data there are different emp-IDs than in your XML... Please provide actual (but reduced!) sample data, actual (but reduced!) sample XML with new/overlapping IDs and the expected output. From the existing sample data how should one know, which data you want  to modifiy?

Comment: Note: there's a word in the last paragraph - "shredd", which I left as is (removed other commentary) as I was not entirely sure whether it was meant to be "shred" or on the off chance another word (shared?)

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, we:

- Filter out XML nodes for records that need to be updated
- Append to the XML nodes generated from the updated records

We avoid using XML DML statements.

```sql
SELECT *
INTO #Employees
FROM (VALUES
(7341, 'SMITH',      'CLERK'    , CONVERT(DATE,'17-DEC-1980')),
(7482, 'ALLEN',      'SALESMAN' , CONVERT(DATE, '20-FEB-1981'))
)v(Empn, Ename, Job, HireDate)

-- This is your existing XML data, which contains many <employee> nodes
DECLARE @Xml XML = 
'
<employees>
    <employee>
        <empno>7341</empno>
        <ename>SMITH</ename>
        <job>CLERK</job>
        <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate>
    </employee>    
    <employee>
        <empno>7482</empno>
        <ename>ALLEN</ename>
        <job>SALESMAN</job>
        <hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <empno>111</empno>
        <ename>JAMES</ename>
        <job>TESTER</job>
        <hiredate>20-FEB-1999</hiredate>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <empno>222</empno>
        <ename>BOB</ename>
        <job>TESTER</job>
        <hiredate>20-FEB-1999</hiredate>
    </employee>
</employees>'


SELECT node.query('.')
FROM (
            -- Return only those nodes from XML, which do not match any records in #Employees table
            SELECT   t.e.query('.')
            FROM @Xml.nodes('/employees/employee') t(e)
            WHERE t.e.value('(empno)[1]', 'INT') NOT IN (
                SELECT Empn
                FROM #Employees
            )

            UNION ALL

            SELECT (
                    SELECT   [empno] = Empn
                            ,[ename] = Ename
                            ,[job] = Job
                            ,[hiredate] = HireDate
                    FROM #Employees
                    WHERE Empn = e.Empn
                    FOR XML PATH('employee'), TYPE
            )
            FROM #Employees e
) t(node)
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('employees')
```